# What is the meaning of the notation $Ber(y|σ(\textbf{w}^T x))$

Tags: statistics

In my textbook, "Probabilistic Machine Learning" in ch13:

> We discussed logistic regression, which, in the binary case,
> corresponds to the model $p(y | \textbf{x}, \textbf{w}) =
> Ber(y|σ(\textbf{w}^T x))$, and in the multiclass case corresponds to
> the model $p(y|x, W) = Cat(y|\text{softmax}(\textbf{W}\textbf{x}))$

I understand what a bernouilli trial is, but I'm confused by this notation. (The "Ber" function)

Comment: I think it means the probability of a $1$ result/outcome (or class positive) given the sigmoid activation of a linear combination of the $x_i$ features, which is a real number in the range $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 0):

From the book, equation $2.67$ and $2.88$:

$$Ber(y|\theta)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  1 - \theta \;\;\;\text{if} \; y = 0\\
                  \theta \; \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{if} \; y = 1
                \end{array}
              \right.$$

$$Cat(y|\theta) = \prod_{c=1}^C \theta_c^{(y=c)} $$